# python - Conditional list formatting

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

On Python 3  I am trying to write a function `format_list(items)` that takes a list `items` containing 1 or 2 string elements and returns a string containing the elements.
Assume that the list being passed will always contain one or two elements (ie, it won't be empty and it won't contain more than two elements).

The conditions are:

1. If the list contains a single element, that element is returned by the function, unchanged.
2. If the list contains two elements, they are returned in a single string with the first element left justified in a field of width 10 followed by a vertical bar ('|') followed by the second element right justified in a field of width 10. You may assume the elements are strings with at most 10 characters each.

So `print(format_list(['abc']))` would produce:

```
abc
```

And `print(format_list(['Dave', '14']))` would produce:

```
Dave   |   14
```

**I have no idea where to even start....**

Comment: you can start with the [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html)

Comment: more specifically, [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

Comment: Thanks, I have read it before but maybe I need a refresher...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def format_list(l):
    if len(l)==1: return l[0]
    else:
        return '{:<10}|{:>10}'.format(l[0],l[1])

for l in [['abc'],['Dave', '14']]:        
    print(format_list(l))
```

Prints:

```
abc
Dave      |        14
```

Look at the [.format](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method and the [.format mini language](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: Thanks, that makes so much sense.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like homework, so a couple clues to get you going:

- `% formatting`  (e.g. `"Hello %s!" % some_var` --> `"Hello World!"` if `some_var == "World"`)
- `len(some_list)` --> number of items in list

Oh, and since I don't want to look it up:

`"%10s" % 'word'` --> `......word` ( a dot is a space )

`"%-10s" % 'word'` --> `word......`

Answer (score -1):

```
def format_list(my_list)
    try:
        return my_list[0].ljust(10) + '|' + my_list[1].rjust(10)
    except IndexError: return my_list
```

Comment: This fails the first condition: it should return the single element, not the list itself.